# Ошибка при запуске Spring прилоложения

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

Класс App с методом Main:

```java
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {

    Client client;
    ConsoleEventLogger eventLogger;

    public App(Client client, ConsoleEventLogger eventLogger) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");

        App app = (App) context.getBean("app");

        app.logEvent("Some event for user 1");
        app.logEvent("Some event for user 2");
    }

    private void logEvent(String msg){
        String message = msg.replaceAll(client.getId(), client.getFullName());
        eventLogger.logEvent(message);
    }
}
```

```java
public class Client {

    public Client(String id, String fullName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    private String id;
    private String fullName;

    public Client() {

    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
}
```

```java
public class ConsoleEventLogger implements EventLogger {

    public void logEvent(String msg) {
        String message = msg;
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <bean id="app" class="App">
        <constructor-arg ref="client"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="eventLogger"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="eventLogger" class="ConsoleEventLogger"/>
    <bean id="client" class="Client"/>

    <bean/>
</beans>
```

ОШИБКА:

```java
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=65134:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar;D:\JetBrainsProjects\com.yet.spring.core\target\classes;C:\Users\Артур\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.2.3.RELEASE\spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.2.3.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.2.3.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.2.3.RELEASE\spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.2.3.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.2.3.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\5.2.3.RELEASE\spring-context-support-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.2.3.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.2.3.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar" App
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unnamed bean definition specifies neither 'class' nor 'parent' nor 'factory-bean' - can't generate bean name
Offending resource: class path resource [config.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:463)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:405)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.processBeanDefinition(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:176)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:96)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:257)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:637)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at App.main(App.java:15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не может найти файл config.xml, который должен лежать у вас в ресурсах. Возможно в maven прописаны правила которые при сборке проекта, то есть после команды `mvn clean install` выносят этот файл например в папочку **config**

Для того, чтобы решить вашу проблему нужно сделать следующее:

1) Проверить, установлен ли у вас maven командой `mvn -v`

2) Ввести команду `mvn clean install` в папке проекта

3) Проверить наличие файла `config.xml`

Comment: при вводе команды в cmd.exe выдает ошибку `Error: Could not find or load main class или
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: или`, хотя мавен у меня установле достаточно давно и проблем я никогда не испытывал

Comment: надо прописать org.apache.maven.plugins, с указанием пути к Main классу в файле pom.xml, как тут [указано](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366373/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)